# How to create and maintain infinite number of database connections in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

Similar to tools like Retool, I'm looking to create a tool where developers can connect their own databases and query.

At the moment, to connect and query the respective database, I do the following:

- Establish a connection to the DB given the credentials save
- Query
- Destroy the connection

This is unfortunately slow and takes about 1.5-2s to finish.

Another alternative is to save the connection in memory and reuse it when needed.

Thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: What you're describing is connection pooling: https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling

Comment: @AaronLS I thought pools only work for 1 database, not multiple different ones

Comment: No server can keep an infinite amount of connections open. However, you can of course cache them, and close them only when they are evicted from your cache.

Comment: Time doesn’t mean anything without the details: Where does your code spend the time?

Comment: Pooling works fine for multiple databases.  The pool understands the state of the pooled connections in order to determine which ones are eligible for reuse in a given context.